# how to reference problems by the text label in an exercise envioronment

Tags: cross-referencing, exercises

I am using the exercise package, as illustrated in the following example:

```
\begin{Exercise}[
title={blah},
label={modernOpticsLecture2:pr2}
]
foo
\end{Exercise}
```

I can put a reference to this problem by doing something like:

```
In \ref{modernOpticsLecture2:pr2} we show that
```

which shows up with a 2.2 hyperlink:

```
In 2.2 we show that
```

but would prefer the reference include a bit more text (i.e. prefixed by exercise) like so:

```
In Exercise 2.2 we show that
```

For now I've just prefixed by `\ref` with the text 'Exercise', but noticed that in my .aux file I have something like:

```
\newlabel{modernOpticsLecture2:pr2}{{2.2}{38}{Problems\relax }{Exercise.2.2}{}}
```

which seems to imply that there's probably a way to directly reference this by the `Exercise.2.2` name that's tucked away in the .aux file encoded using this `\newlabel` command.

I was wondering how that would be done?

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how to use `cleveref` together with the `exercise` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package automatically generate this kind of format for cross-references. Instead of using `\ref`, you now use `\cref` (or `\Cref` at the beginning of a sentence.)

You have to make `cleveref` aware of the `Exercise` environment from the `exercise` package; this can be done using the `\crefname` (for `\cref`) and `\Crefname` (for `\Cref`) commands:

```
\crefname{<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}
\Crefname{<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}
```

A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{Exercise}{Exercise}{Exercises}
\Crefname{Exercise}{Exercise}{Exercises}

\begin{document}

The reader is asked to demonstrate this fact in~\cref{modernOpticsLecture2:pr2}.
\begin{Exercise}[
title={Some exercise},
label={modernOpticsLecture2:pr2}
]
Test exercise
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]